# RavenDB document design, patching, and index creation

Tags: ravendb

I am revisiting RavenDB after a brief experiment quite a while ago. At the moment I'm considering document design which is nested 3 levels deep, i.e.

```
public class UserEvent
{
    public UserEvent()
    {
        Shows = new List<Show>();
    }
    public readonly string IdPrefix = "Events/";
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Show> Shows { get; set; }
}

public class Show
{
    public Show()
    {
        Entries = new List<ShowEntry>();
    }
    public readonly string IdPrefix = "Shows/";
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string EventId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public List<ShowEntry> Entries { get; set; }
}

public class ShowEntry
{
    public readonly string IdPrefix = "ShowEntries/";
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string DogId { get; set; }
    public string OwnerName { get; set; }
    public EntryClass Class { get; set; }
}
```

First of all, is this a sensible design? A `UserEvent` generally has a few (less than 6) `Show`, but a `Show` can have between tens to hundreds of `ShowEntry`. I have included `DogId` in `ShowEntry` but maybe later I will change it to a property of `Dog` type. A `Dog` is of a particular `Breed`, and a `Breed` belongs to a `Group`. The `Dog` side of the story will have to be another question but for now I'm interested in the `UserEvent` side.

If my documents are designed this way can I use the Patching API to add items into the `Entries` collection within a `Show`? I would like to have an index which will summarise Entries based on Dog properties. Will indexes get processed if an a document is patched?

Answer (score 0):

Your design certainly looks sensible from an outside perspective. The big question you need to ask yourself is, "What do you plan on querying a majority of the time?"

For instance, Show seems to be a fairly common object that would benefit from being an Aggregate Root (from Domain Driven Design). I find that when organizing my documents, the most important question is, "how often do you plan on querying the object."

To answer your last question, Patching should definitely causing re-indexing.